# Markup feature in images in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, markup, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've created a chat app, where user can chat and share images. Now I need to add feature where user can edit and perform some annotation on images. I've heard from iOS 9 there's a new feature called markup to perform editting on images. I've checked `UIActivityViewController` and couldn't find in it. Is this feature available and can it fit to my requirement? If not, is there any other alternatives that I can approach?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes you are Right Markup feature is available from ios 9.

> iOS 9 has introduced a set of markup tools for images that you attach
>   with a message in the Mail app.

To use this feature,

1) Open the Mail app and  compose a new message (or reply to an old one if that’s what you need to do).

2) Tap and hold on the message body area and in the floating actions bar, tap the Insert Photo or Video option. From your camera roll, insert a photo.

3) Tap and hold on the photo and in the floating actions bar that appears on the photo, tap the new ‘Markup’ option.

--> Your photo will be enter in Editing mode.

Markup tool will look like this ,

[image]

From the link [whats-new](http://www.apple.com/in/ios/whats-new/) you will find that apple implement markup option for mail.

[image]

**So, As per your Question** , Markup image facility provided bydefault by apple in Mail. so, i think you can't implement it programatically. **but** when user will open the mail from UIActivitycontroller from your application then user will get **Markup feature** with following above procedure. (But user have to manually do process to enable Markup feature)

You can also check video on youtube ,

[How to markup and annotate an attachment in iOS 9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geGCuKEgEEY)

Reference link regarding markup feature,

[ios-9-markup-annotate-email-attachments](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/06/14/ios-9-markup-annotate-email-attachments/)

I hope this info is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so I guess I cant use this feature for my requirement. Are you aware of any other class or framework which can be used for image annotation?

Comment: There are lots of Library available on github but this all works before you present UIActivityview controller. so, you need to add extra functionality in your application to design image. This is just example link , https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor but you can find many on https://www.cocoacontrols.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QLPreviewController for basic mark up. You will need to save your image to a URL first. Then you have the option to use QLPreviewController to save edits to the same URL, to files or another URL. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewcontroller for full details.

Import QuickLook and create a function to save your image to a URL and instantiate the QLPreviewController. You will also need to add extensions QLPreviewControllerDataSource and QLPreviewControllerDelegate to your view controller.

```
import UIKit
import QuickLook

public class YourViewController{
    .
    .
    .
    private var savedImageURL: URL {
        return FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Image").appendingPathExtension("jpg")
    }

    private func edit(image: UIImage){
        guard let data = imageToEdit.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1),
              (try? data.write(to: savedImageURL)) != nil else {
          assert(false, "Can't save image")
          return
        }
        let qlPreviewController = QLPreviewController()
        qlPreviewController.dataSource = self
        qlPreviewController.delegate = self
        present(qlPreviewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

You will need to adjust the data source for QLPreviewController. For this example it is one image at a single URL.
You also want to return the data from the delegate methods, as well as specify how the edited data is saved. We are using .updateContents for the save type, this will update the edited photo at the same URL inputted.

```
extension YourViewController: QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate{

    public func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
        1
    }

    public func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        return savedImageURL as NSURL
    }

    public func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, didUpdateContentsOf previewItem: QLPreviewItem) {
        guard let modifiedContentsURL = previewItem.previewItemURL,
              let data = try? Data(contentsOf: modifiedContentsURL),
              let image = UIImage(data: data) else {return}
        // Process edited image as you wish
    }

    public func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, editingModeFor previewItem: QLPreviewItem) -> QLPreviewItemEditingMode {
        .updateContents
    }
}
```